Outdoor stringer sister is bowing and seperating from the stringer. Should I reattach it?
The stairs bringing my outdoor deck to ground level are about 12 ft long with 4 stringers, 2 outer and 2 inner. The inner stringers have sistering, I am imagining to reduce bounciness walking up and down. The sistering is bowing so much it is separating from the stringer. I can even see where one of the sisterings actually moved the stringer slightly from it's original position on the ground slab.
Facts I know:
I know little about wood. There I said it.
The wood does not appear to be pressure treated. I don't know if it should be for this application but putting it out there.
I very mechanically inclined and DIY almost everything.
The house is about 5 years old now. I've been living here almost a year, so it's not old construction.
Last year I moved here to Colorado Springs. Temperatures are extreme and range from really hot to below freezing (sometimes in the same day it seems.) Humidity is very low. Temperature expansion and shrinkage is very much a concern with materials here.
The supporting structure and all the railings are all wood of some sort, The decking and stair treads are some sort of synthetic composite material.
Things I have considered:
I could just use a series of C clamps to push them back together, hammer the nails back in, and place screws since they will be more resistant to allowing the sistering to pull away from the stringers.
I am wary about this because I don't know if the sistering will continue to bow, and eventually bow the stringers more than it already has. Is this even an issue I should worry about?
I could put horizontal bracing between the sisters to encourage them to resist bowing. I don't know if this is even a good idea.
I could just remove the sistering altogether and put fresh straighter sistering, using screws next time (or is there a reason they used nails instead of screws?) If so what kind of wood am I looking for?
Bottom of stairs pic:


Pictures will help.  Bowing sisters is odd.  Maybe wrong wood was used?

Neither the stringer or the sistered members look like treated material.

@MichaelKaras could they perhaps be redwood?

I would clamp them back together and then use deck screws to refasten the sistered members to the stringers. If the bottom edges of the two are not even then use additional clamping to realign them before screwing together.
It can be helpful to drill some pilot holes part way through the sistered members to allow the deck screws to firmly pull the them to the sides of the stringers.

IDK that I'd use deck screws.  Some galvanized (or stainless) nuts and bolts with fender washers would probably be more resistant to pulling apart in the future.

Bolts + washers are always a good temporary plan too.  I'm a fan of construction screws myself.  100% agree though. just needs come extra coercing.

If it was my own deck stair repair I would use TimberLok screws.
